# How to reduce complexity of a long boolean expression?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, algorithm, complexity-theory

I have a boolean expression to evaluate that is pretty long with a lot of different cases:

```
return (a && b && c) ||
(d && e && f) ||
...
```

This should return a boolean!

a, b, c, d, e and f being simple equality comparison and being all different.
This continues for 12 lines and gives me a Cyclomatic Complexity of 44

I tried to look at the Map object in order to reduce the complexity but did not find a way to do it.

How could I reduce the complexity of such an expression ?

Comment: *"a, b, c, d, e and f being simple equality comparison*" Is the value used in equality comparison relevant to the question? (Are they all being compared to the same value)

Comment: @adiga No the values are not relevant to the question. They are all different

Comment: @AnthonyMaffert what is expected value from your return is a boolean value or the last value of group where all are true i.e `(a && b && c)` c if all values are true

Comment: @CodeManiac it expects to return a boolean value

Comment: Do these equality comparisons repeat? E.g. are there several combinations of positive and/or negative instances a to f or are they a to z with little to no repeated comparisons?

Comment: Is that a programming question or a Boolean logic question?
If it is a Boolean logic question, you can use standard methods to reduce Boolean equations like Espresso does (from Stanford University I believe).

Comment: @hajef Little to no repeated comparisons

Comment: There are minimization approaches like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map (visual method, applicable to a few variables only) or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm (arbitrary amount of variables) if it is about simplifying the boolean expression itself.

Comment: If there are no redundant information, how do you expect to reduce them? You can change the syntax but cou can't reduce the logic. You can take a look at Quine–McCluskey, but if there are close to no repeated comparisons, that won't help much. Edit: @tevemadar, Carnaugh won't work for that many variables. We'd be lucky if there was a pair of clauses with a total of just 3 parameters and that's about as much as Carnaught can candle.

Comment: @hajef: I do not think that the *visual method, applicable to a few variables only* remark suggests it is applicable for a lot of variables. However for understanding the what and how, it is a better start than directly jumping at Quine–McCluskey.

Comment: @tevemadar true. Plus I mixed some things up at my last comment. 4 to 5 variables can be reasonably handled by Carnough, requring 2 to 3 dimensions.

Comment: @hajef: at the end OP did not show a long boolean expression to simplify, and Nina Scholz did not show a way to simplify a long boolean expression. The world remains balanced.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "reduce the complexity." (Complexity is an especially loaded term in computer science.)

Comment: For boolean minimisation I've always used Espresso (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso_heuristic_logic_minimizer). I used to use it when I was designing digital hardware (both for work and fun). The source is available online - just google "espresso boolean minimisation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not reduce the complexity of the given expression.

A slower approach, but maybe a little more structured, is to group the expressions and evaluate with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for the outer array and [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for the inner arrays with a short circuit.

```
return [[a, b, c], [d, e, f]].some(a => a.every(Boolean));
```

Comment: Nice idea but this will result in `Boolean value`, where as `return (a && b && c) || ...` will result in value

Comment: the values are *"simple equality comparison"*, according to the OP.

Comment: @NinaScholz i got confused with the question, this is perfectly fine as OP wants Boolean value as output

Comment: Since js use short-circuit evalutions, why would this reduce the complexity ? I would even think that it will increase execution time (2 differents things but still matters)

Comment: Tried right now and by my bench (with just 6 vars) your way of doing is 1.2 to 2.5 times slower than OP's one